# How to implement expand/collapse functionality for unordered list in Spring MVC

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

I'm trying to build a navigation for my Spring MVC application and I have a multilevel unordered list in my jsp page. I'd like to have a possibility of expanding/collapsing on image click (maybe a little "plus" sign). Is there a way to do this in Spring MVC application?

Edit..
For now I'm trying just to achieve simple expand and collapse (I haven't added "plus" sign images etc.) This is the last thing I've tried

script.js

> $('.listitem').click(function () {
>       $(this).find('ul').slideToggle(); });

index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %> <html> <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${context}/js/script.js"></script> </head> <body>

    <div style="float: left; width: 20%">
        <h4>${treeView}</h4>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 80%" id="thePage">
        <iframe id="frame1" name="frame1" scrolling="auto" runat="server" style="float: left; width: 100%; height: 950px;"></iframe>
    </div> </body> </html>
```

What I have rendered...

```
<html> <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script> </head> <body>


<div style="float: left; width: 20%">
    <h4><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
        <ul class="list">MyList
            <li class="listitem">
                <ul>HO.jws
                    <li class="listitem">
                        <ul>HO1.jpr
                            <li class="listitem">
                                <ul><a href="http://localhost:8000/resources//HO1//file1.html"
                                       target="frame1">file1.ext</a>
                                    <li class="listitem">
                                        <ul>Names</ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="listitem">
                                        <ul>Functions</ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="listitem">
                                        <ul>Properties</ul>
                                    </li> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring MVC just acts as a controller mechanism, what you'd do here is control the "plus" sign with some sort of javascript that would invoke the Spring MVC controller to get the list and when you clicked the + symbol, it just collapsed or expanded a list in the HTML.

You could just get the contents of the list on page load, saying in jQuery with `$(document).ready()`, get the list an build the html then all the + symbol does is change if this list appears in the DOM.

Comment: I tried several things, but for some reason none of the javascript code does not seem to work. I've included javascript files properly, and I've added <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**"  location="/WEB-INF/pages/js/" /> to my servlet.xml

And I already have my controller rendering the list, it's just expanded all the time, and I'd like to avoid that, as it's huge...

Comment: Please provide the JS you're using.  Where are you storing the JS in your project location?  It sounds like the JS location isn't being read properly.

Comment: Here, I just edited my original question. Thanks for trying to help me btw :D

Comment: If you just do a console.log() when listitem is clicked?  Does it fire?

Comment: As I'm not sure where to check for console.log() output, I tried alert("it fired"). Nothing happened :S

Comment: Yeah, so first work out why none of your JS fires.  Can you get to script.js if you look at the source of the page?  In fact, a better question would've been working out why none of your JS fires in Spring MVC.

Comment: If i put it between head tags in index.jsp, it does fire. So it's probably not the case that JS does not fire in Spring MVC, it's probably me doing something wrong with the js function?

Comment: If you put console.log() in the <head> tag in a script and it works that proves nothing, you need to work out if the code in your script.js can fire a console.log().  When I say js does not fire in SpringMVC I mean that SpringMVC isn't find the js folder in your project.

Comment: Compare your XML and javascript locations to the open source Spring MVC application I wrote https://github.com/david99world/ESPNPlayerViewer try using the same locations for your JS if it's not firing at all (as you mentioned above that alert didn't fire in the JS file).